# How do I programmatically configure the accelerometer for the iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode, accelerometer

I'm not sure how to set the null point of the iPhone in Xcode. I have an app that has a [`UIimage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that moves around the screen and works well.

What I want to do is set it indefinitely so that when the iPhone is held as you would when reading a text (i.e 45 degree angle) it is level (e.g., image doesn't move). I don't need [calibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibration) options for the user to set I just need to set it in the code.

Comment: You can hold the device at the "comfortable angle", then record down the metrics and hard code it into the calibration logic.